# Why my edit suggestion is rejected?

Tags: discussion, editing

I have edited the content of question at [find the edit here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/78127). I want to know why my edit is rejected by two users?

Comment: "This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have rejected it too, as I did it in the past with many of your suggestions IIRC. Thanks for bringing this up here, so I can address the issue directly:

There are edit suggestions that do not make the post worse but also are not really worth it. Keep in mind that at least three other users have to review your suggestions, don't waste their time for nothing.

#### Examples:

- change one or two spelling mistakes but leave dozens of other mistakes untouched. If you are going to fix spelling and/or grammar, make it so that the overall quality of the post increases
- edits that do nothing more than applying your personal taste of formatting where the original formatting was good enough to be readable. Pure formatting edits are fine if they fix broken code blocks and lists, add paragraphs to a wall of text and so on. But for example just making some words bold is not a good edit.
- removing fluff like "Thank you in advance". I do that too when I reword a question to make it more readable or together with other changes, but not as sole purpose of an edit. It is useless but does not really hurt.

In this particular example, linking the website is not only **not** a significant improvement, but also potentially harmful. The original poster might not want a backlink from StackExchange to their site, leave it up to them to decide if they want to link it or not.

---

And because I recently noticed these, here are examples for very good edit suggestions https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/46317/grgarside?tab=activity

Comment: Hi fschmengler, Okay i understand what you told. Thank you. I had highlighted this with not angry. Just i would like to know the reason. Good explanation. Best of Luck.

Comment: That's good, no reason to be angry for anyone :) Thanks for your contributions!

Comment: Frankly i am telling you that actually i hurt when you rejects my suggestion. But after i realized from that when i receive your explanation.:)

Comment: Hi. how to know that who downvoted and who upvoted on our questionand answer ?

Comment: Get hired at StackExchange :) AFAIK even the mods cannot see this information

Comment: Oh ok. thank you for reply

Answer (score 0):

Assume small changes can not be accepted. For more information you can check with [Why was my edit rejected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164448/why-was-my-edit-rejected)

I suggest you to ask stackexchange quires at https://meta.stackexchange.com/ to get more user responses.

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi, i have seen your link suggestion bro. good but there is no effetc on the content with my edit.

Comment: The reason can not be specific but assume small changes can not be accepted. Approving an edit is completely based on an user or who asked question have a right.

Comment: Ok bro thanks for spending time and took the responsibility to exolain. i accepted.